# RxJS event order guarantee

Tags: events, system.reactive, rxjs

while exploring rx for our project, we ran into the following puzzler:
We have one stream S1 that can receive two distinct events (A and B).
If we create two separate streams (Sx1 and Sx2) from that stream (S1) that subscribe specifically for either A or B events (Sx1 for A and Sx2 for B), is there any guarantee that the subscribers will receive the events
in the order they arrive in S1?

Comment: This seems like a fairly straightforward thing to confirm yourself, is there some code you have where this is not the case? In the general case order in=order out

Comment: what other order _could_ you expect in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what merging method you chose to carry out which will determine how the results are given back.

Take a look at [RxMArbles](http://rxmarbles.com/) it has great visual examples.

for this case I'd say [Concat](http://rxmarbles.com/#concat) would keep it in the same order the events went in but if you are dealing with async data this might not be the best option. look at the `COMBINING OPERATORS` on RxMarble